# the anchor in javascript does not work correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Playback Steps:

In the header, click on any of the links with anchors:
##bankaccount
#pack
#platform
#acq
##scorecard
##intrade
#form
Scroll the page to the top
Reload the page
Actual result:

When reloading a page with an anchor in the url, there is no scrolling to the block.

Expected result:

When a page with an anchor in the url is reloaded, a scroll to the block occurs.

The problem is that while the page is not fully loaded, the scroll works, but when the page is fully loaded, the scroll goes back up

```
import React from 'react';

const useScrollToLocation = () => {
    React.useEffect(() => {
        const hash = window.location.hash;
        const id = hash.replace('#', '');
        const element = document.getElementById(id);
        window.location.hash = '';
        if (element) {
            window.location.hash = id;
        }
    }, []);
};
export default useScrollToLocation;
```

Comment: Maybe it's due to `if (element) {}`. Did you try removing it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this custom hook.

```
const useScrollToLocation = (location?: Location | undefined) => {
  const [scrolledTo, setScrolledTo] = useState<string>();

  const safeLocation = location || window.location;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!safeLocation.hash) return;

    const idOrName = safeLocation.hash.slice(1);

    if (idOrName !== scrolledTo) {
      const element =
        document.getElementById(idOrName) ||
        document.getElementsByName(idOrName).item(0);

      if (!element) return setScrolledTo(undefined);

      element.scrollIntoView();
      setScrolledTo(idOrName);
    }
  });
};
```

Usage:

```
const location = useLocation();
useScrollToLocation(location);
```